# Rails is not generating new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi everyone and thanks for being such a great community.

I'm starting a new project with rails , and I am starting a already have problem. After creating a new app , I'm trying to generate a new controller so I can get to work and rails is throwing this error. I did all fix rails suggested and I sill got the same problem

Error here :

```
gdiop@localhost:~/Desktop//app> rails new wp
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb                                                                           
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb                                                                           
      create  app/assets/images/.keep                                                                                     
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/update
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
         run  bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.                                               
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.4
Using minitest 5.10.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.2.0
Using rack 2.0.3
Using nio4r 2.1.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.1.4
Using bundler 1.15.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using puma 3.9.1
Using sass 3.4.24
Using tilt 2.0.7
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
Using nokogiri 1.8.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using mime-types 3.1
Using uglifier 3.2.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using rb-inotify 0.9.8
Using activesupport 5.0.3
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.6
Using listen 3.0.8
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using globalid 0.4.0
Using activemodel 5.0.3
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using spring 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using activejob 5.0.3
Using activerecord 5.0.3
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using actionview 5.0.3
Using actionpack 5.0.3
Using actioncable 5.0.3
Using actionmailer 5.0.3
Using railties 5.0.3
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
Using web-console 3.5.1
Using rails 5.0.3
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 62 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
The latest bundler is 1.15.1, but you are currently running 1.15.0.
To update, run `gem install bundler`                                                                                      
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
gdiop@localhost:~/Desktop//app> cd wp
gdiop@localhost:~/Desktop/app/wp> bin/rails generate controller Welcome index
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.8.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/server.rb:9:in `call'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<main>'
gdiop@localhost:~/Desktop/app/wp>
```

I ran bundle install and gem pristine bindex , nothing !! I still have the same error !

Please help !

Thanks

EDIT : I can fire up puma no problem but I cant create a new controller , and here is my gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development



group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

EDIT :

A clean reinstall has fixed my prblem. I didnt wanted to go that extrem but This was the only option I got ...

Comment: anything ? :'-(

Comment: You are using the command "bin/rails generate controller Welcome index". remove "bin/" from your command.

Comment: @InzamamTahir it is not fixing the issue. I have the same problem

Comment: ok. just a wild guess, try this command first: "gem install bundler" and then, generate controller with "rails g controller Welcome index"

Comment: Update bundler first

Answer (score 1):

Try using `bundle exec rails g controller Welcome index`

Using `bundle exec` will lock all calls to the specific gem's you've specified in the Gemfile instead of the global installation.

Try commenting out the following gems:

```
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
```

Then run `bundle update` after this finishestry to run the command again: `bundle exec rails g controller Welcome index`

Comment: I got this : bundle exec rails g controller Welcome index
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.8.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: @coco can you post your GEMFILE?

Comment: @OneNeptume. I run on OpenSUse ! It cant be windows ?

Comment: @coco If you're not on windows, why do you have the bottom two lines of your GEMFILE? Anyways, try the updated answer, spring can cause weird problems on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line to your gemfile

```
gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
```

also try

```
 rails generate controller welcome
```

without index method and add manually later.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `bin/rails` in your command. Use:

```
rails g controller Welcome index
```